# Select all many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following tables:

```
author
--------------
id int(11)
name varchar

author_type
---------------
id int(11)
type varchar

author_has_type
---------------
author_id int(11)
author_type_id int(11)
```

I'm trying to write a query that does the following;

Given a an author type it will display the following

```
author.name           types
-The authors name-    -All types of the author-
```

Now the query I'm trying to do it with is

```
Select author.name, GROUP_CONCAT(author_type.type) as types
from author
left join author_has_type on author.id = author_has_type.author_id
left join author_type on author_has_type.author_type_id = author_type.id
where author_type.type = "EXAMPLE TYPE"
```

However when I do this it just returns just the given type in the group_concat. I understand why this is happening but is there a way to get every type of that author?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `group by` and to remove the `where` clause:

```
Select a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.type) as types
from author a left join
     author_has_type aht
     on a.id = aht.author_id left join
     author_type t
     on aht.author_type_id = t.id
group by a.name;
```

EDIT:

I think what you want is:

```
Select a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.type) as types
from author a left join
     author_has_type aht
     on a.id = aht.author_id left join
     author_type t
     on aht.author_type_id = t.id
group by a.name
having max(author_type.type = 'EXAMPLE TYPE') > 0;
```

Comment: Yes but that will just get all authors and all their types. I am looking to get all authors and all their types, having the specified type in the where clause.

Comment: @user2827048 . . . Your question clarifies the question.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the grouping to your query. And to limit which rows are to be output use HAVING with a subquery.

```
SELECT author.name, GROUP_CONCAT(author_type.type) as types
FROM author
LEFT JOIN author_has_type on author.id = author_has_type.author_id
LEFT JOIN author_type on author_has_type.author_type_id = author_type.id
GROUP BY (author.name)
HAVING author.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM author 
    JOIN author_has_type ON author.id = author_has_type.author_id
    JOIN author_type ON author_has_type.author_type_id = author_type.id
    WHERE author_type.type = "EXAMPLE TYPE"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT author.name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(author_type.type) as types
  FROM author
  LEFT JOIN author_has_type on author.id = author_has_type.author_id
  LEFT JOIN author_type on author_has_type.author_type_id = author_type.id
       (SELECT author.ID 
         FROM author
         LEFT JOIN author_has_type on author.id = author_has_type.author_id
         LEFT JOIN author_type on author_has_type.author_type_id = author_type.id
        WHERE author_type.type = "EXAMPLE TYPE") temp
    ON author.id=temp.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    author.name, 
    result.types 
FROM (
    SELECT author.id, GROUP_CONCAT(types.type) AS types
    FROM 
        author
    INNER JOIN author_has_type
        ON author.id = author_has_type.author_id
    INNER JOIN author_type 
        ON author_has_type.author_type_id = author_type.id 
        AND author_type.type = "funny"
    INNER JOIN author_has_type AS has_types
        ON author.id = has_types.author_id
    INNER JOIN author_type AS types
        ON has_types.author_type_id = types.id 
    GROUP BY author.id
) AS result 
INNER JOIN author 
    USING(id)
```

Add two Inner Joins to filter onto the type you want to look for. Then use the next two joins to get all the types of the author.

Group the query and put it into a subquery. In the outer query use the result to join the authordata onto your result.

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98b30c/2)